# How to select the records depend on PCs to reduce dimensionality in Rapidminer?

Tags: pca, rapidminer, dimensionality-reduction

I am a new in Rapidminer, so i have a huge dataset and i use Principle component analysis to reduce dimensionality, the problem is when i get the PCs i do not know how to select the records depend on it how can i make a new dataset which is reduced ?

this what i am tried to use :

[image]

and this what i get :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could use the "Weight by PCA" operator to calculate weights for attribute importance and then use the "Select by Weights" operator to reduce the number of attributes in your original data set.

Check the attached example process below (just c&p the XML into your RapidMiner process window).
Also feel free to take a look or ask questions at the [RapidMiner community](https://community.rapidminer.com/)

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><process version="9.2.000">
<context>
<input/>
<output/>
<macros/>
</context>
<operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="6.0.002" expanded="true" name="Root" origin="GENERATED_TUTORIAL">
<parameter key="logverbosity" value="init"/>
<parameter key="random_seed" value="2001"/>
<parameter key="send_mail" value="never"/>
<parameter key="notification_email" value=""/>
<parameter key="process_duration_for_mail" value="30"/>
<parameter key="encoding" value="SYSTEM"/>
<process expanded="true">
  <operator activated="true" class="retrieve" compatibility="9.2.000" expanded="true" height="68" name="Sonar" origin="GENERATED_TUTORIAL" width="90" x="112" y="34">
    <parameter key="repository_entry" value="//Samples/data/Sonar"/>
  </operator>
  <operator activated="true" class="weight_by_pca" compatibility="9.2.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Weight by PCA" width="90" x="313" y="34">
    <parameter key="normalize_weights" value="true"/>
    <parameter key="sort_weights" value="true"/>
    <parameter key="sort_direction" value="ascending"/>
    <parameter key="component_number" value="1"/>
  </operator>
  <operator activated="true" class="select_by_weights" compatibility="9.2.000" expanded="true" height="103" name="Select by Weights" width="90" x="581" y="34">
    <parameter key="weight_relation" value="greater equals"/>
    <parameter key="weight" value="0.5"/>
    <parameter key="k" value="10"/>
    <parameter key="p" value="0.5"/>
    <parameter key="deselect_unknown" value="true"/>
    <parameter key="use_absolute_weights" value="true"/>
  </operator>
  <connect from_op="Sonar" from_port="output" to_op="Weight by PCA" to_port="example set"/>
  <connect from_op="Weight by PCA" from_port="weights" to_op="Select by Weights" to_port="weights"/>
  <connect from_op="Weight by PCA" from_port="example set" to_op="Select by Weights" to_port="example set input"/>
  <connect from_op="Select by Weights" from_port="example set output" to_port="result 1"/>
  <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
  <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
  <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="162"/>
</process>
</operator>
</process>
```